# Как скопировать текст в БО [закрыто]

Tags: javascript

Собственно, как скопировать текст в буфер обмена, через js?
Везде находил или для каждого браузера отдельно, или на jQuery.
Думаю, многие сталкивались. Подскажите функцию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[zeroclipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/)

> Обеспечивает функциональность "Копировать в буфер обмена" для вашего веб-сайта с помощью JavaScript и Flash.

Comment: огромное спасибо, за пару часов разобрался (: